# error_reporting 4983

Tags: php

When I use ini_set to check my error_reporting level, I get a weird value ( 4983 ) that I can't find anywhere by googling.

does anyone know how to determine what exactly this level is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It's a combination of the flags you can test here:

http://www.bx.com.au/tools/ultimate-php-error-reporting-wizard

```
1       E_ERROR     
2       E_WARNING   
4       E_PARSE     
8       E_NOTICE    
16      E_CORE_ERROR    
32      E_CORE_WARNING  
64      E_COMPILE_ERROR     
128     E_COMPILE_WARNING   
256     E_USER_ERROR    
512     E_USER_WARNING  
1024    E_USER_NOTICE   
2048    E_STRICT    
4096    E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR     
8192    E_DEPRECATED    
16384   E_USER_DEPRECATED
```

`4983` is the **combination** of `E_ERROR, E_WARNING, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_USER_ERROR, E_USER_WARNING, E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR`

Comment: what i ignore this problem in any way ?

Answer (score 0):

The error reporting level is saved as a bit mask. `E_ERROR` for instance has the value `1`, which in binary is `0000 0001`. `E_WARNING` is `2`, which in binary is `0000 0010`. Combined they form the bit mask `0000 0011`, which is the value `3` in decimal.

Basically, you need to convert the [error reporting constant's values](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) and the value 4983 to binary to figure it out. You can also loop through all the constants and check if the specific bit is set using `4983 & E_ERROR`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the binary number 1001101110111

Then you have to look in the manual which flag is what. 
If I didn't miss one these are your settings for error_reporting:

E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR
E_USER_WARNING
E_USER_ERROR
E_COMPILE_ERROR
E_CORE_WARNING
E_CORE_ERROR
E_PARSE
E_WARNING
E_ERROR